# Can an azure job with a HTTP Trigger return a http response body?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I have an azure function like this:

```
[FunctionName("DoStuff")]
[return: Queue("stuff-queue")]
public static async Task<StuffContext> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var context = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<StuffContext>();
    context.TransactionId = Guid.NewGuid();
    return context;
}
```

It listens on a https url, deserializes the request body, and send body to the queue. Can I also have it return something (the transaction id in this case) as part of the http response.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I also have it return something (the transaction id in this case) as part of the http response.

Using `[return: Queue("stuff-queue")]` will return the information to the queue. But it could not return a response and add the information to the queue at the same time.

If you want to do, you could refer to my code.It works fine on my side.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Queue("stuff-queue")] IAsyncCollector<string> outputQueue)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string yourinfo = "yourinfo";       
            await outputQueue.AddAsync(yourinfo);
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, yourinfo);

        }
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#output---usage).